# Get the largest signed integer type in C++

Tags: c++, c, signed, unsigned-integer, size-t

Let's say I have to accept a size as an argument to an interface which deals with arrays. For e.x.

```
void doSomethingRelatedToArrays(const size_t length)
```

Here, I used `size_t` with the following in mind:

- length must always be positive
- `size_t` is always typedef-ed to the largest unsigned integer type in the system. `std::size_t` can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type.

However, I should not use unsigned types in my interfaces because the client can pass in a negative number, which is implicitly converted to an unsigned number and I do not have any way of validating it in my method. Refer to Scott Meyer's article on this subject [here](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/sep95.pdf).

So, I should pass in signed integer type to the API. But how can I get the largest signed integer type in the system? Is there any typedef similar to `size_t` which is signed? Or should I just use `size_t` instead?

Comment: POSIX has `ssize_t`.

Comment: Note: C does _not_ define "size_t is always typedef-ed to the largest unsigned integer type in the system".  `uintmax_t` is a better candidate "an unsigned integer type capable of representing any value of any unsigned integer type"

Comment: `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>`

Comment: Scott Meyer article, concerning array sizes, conveniently incorrectly fails valid huge array sizes.  Although this is certainly less  a common issue than incorrect negative sizes, it simply trades one error detection for another.  If the parameter is whole numbers in [INTMAX_MIN...INTMAX_MAX], use `intmax_t`, else if in range [0...UINTMAX_MAX], use `uintmax_t`, if FP, use `long double`, if boolean, use `bool`, etc.

Comment: the signed counterpart of `size_t` is probably [`ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t), but it's still not the largest integer type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I get the largest signed integer type in the system?

In C++11's `<cstdint>` you can find type `intmax_t`, which is defined after the C standard (7.20.1.5):

> The following type designates a signed integer type capable of
>   representing any value of any signed integer type

---

> Is there any typedef similar to size_t which is signed?

No, not in the C++ standard. POSIX defines `ssize_t`, **but**:

- it is not meant to replace `size_t` (which itself is also more restricted by POSIX)
- is not meant to store/pass negative values, but to indicate error:

  > `ssize_t` shall be capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, {SSIZE_MAX}].

---

> So, I should pass in signed integer type to the API. (...) Or should I
>   just use size_t instead?

If your interface is meant to deal with C++ arrays, `size_t` is the only type that is assured by the standard to be able to hold any of the possible array indexes. Using any other type you might (in theory) loose ability to address all of the array (which is even noted in the article you linked).

Using `size_t` for indexing purposes is therefore common and customary - and used by many libraries (including STL).

Comment: `ssize_t` is not the largest signed integer type in 32-bit Linux or 64-bit x32 ABI Linux either

Answer (score 5):

The signed equivalent of `size_t` is simply `ssize_t` but this type is not defined in C99 standard even if it is known to many compilers.

For the C99 standard  the largest signed integer type is defined as `intmax_t`.

Reference : 7. Library / 7.18 Integer types  / 7.18.1.5 Greatest-width integer types

Comment: std::numeric_limits<ssize_t>::max(), std::numeric_limits<ssize_t>::is_signed, etc

Comment: `size_t` is not even the largest integer type. It may have only 16 bits in 16-bit systems or 32 bits in 32-bit systems

Answer (score 4):

The standard type to use is `std::intmax_t` which is defined in `<cstdint>`. To get the maximum value you can use `std::numeric_limits<intmax_t>::max()`.

Sample code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "max size = " << std::numeric_limits<intmax_t>::max() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The largest signed integer type in recent C and C++ standards is `long long`. Until there is a type wider than `long long` you can always use it. If you want to be more future proof, use `intmax_t`.

---

> `size_t` is always typedef-ed to the largest unsigned integer type in the system

## That's completely incorrect!!! ❌

`size_t` in 32-bit systems is typically also a 32-bit type, which obviously **not** the widest type possible. It's only guaranteed to be *big enough to represent the size of the biggest object* on the system. `long long` is obviously much wider in that cases. In many 16-bit systems it has only 16 bits, not even the same range as `long`.

---

In case `size_t` is needed, `ptrdiff_t` can be used as a signed counterpart. But it's not the biggest type either.

> For `char` arrays shorter than `PTRDIFF_MAX`, `std::ptrdiff_t` acts as the signed counterpart of `std::size_t`: it can store the size of the array of any type and is, on most platforms, synonymous with `std::intptr_t`
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t

In C++20 [`std::ssize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) was introduced and guess what, **it also uses `ptrdiff_t` as the signed counterpart of `size_t`**